# angular dynamically generate html file

Tags: angularjs, compilation, routes

I am trying to write a simple CMS system where the content of each page is stored in a database.  When the user tries to access

/pages/abc.html

through angular routing and controller to retrieve the content of that page from the database and generate abc.html on the fly.  I found one way is to add a function to templateUrl to return the page:

```
  .when('/content/pages/:name*', {
    templateUrl: function(parameters) {
      return '/pages/' + parameters.name + '.html';
    },
    controller: 'ContentCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'content'
  })
```

However the issue is I need to have abc.html already exist and then in the controller to compile the DOM content and attach it.  What I am trying to do is not to have the abc.html already exist, but generated on the fly.  This way I can allow my user to add xyz content and when they try to access xyz.html it will be there, without having to create xyz.html template html upfront.  Is there any method I can use to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you need to generate the parameters.name html file? I would think you could define the template as  then pass the html into the controller. If there is a lot of repeated logic, you could make a content component or directive.

Answer (score 0):

What I did for this is write a custom directive.  I pass the directive an array that contain objects that correspond to ui elements.  The objects are defined in JS and all have a .html() function I wrote that generates some html based on the objects properties.  Then to store/restore the structure you can just JSON.stringify the object to insert it in the DB and JSON.parse to get the object back... Only tricky part is you need to store the data type as a property of the object so you can pick the right type.

The directive itself just calls the html() function on each object and concatenates the output then sets the innerHTML of the element.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I could just use the template property to insert any html I want.

```
  .when('/content/pages/:name*', {
    template: function(parameters) {
      return 'hello' + parameters.name;
    },
    controller: 'ContentCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'content'
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do it pass template name as a parameter to the controller:

```
  .when('/content/pages/:name*', {
    templateUrl: function(parameters) {
      return '/pages/:templateName';
    },
    controller: 'ContentCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'content'
  })
```

And in the controller, create the required HTML (if not existing) and then in template include the HTML using `ng-include`:

```
<div ng-include="template.url" ng-if="template.url"></div>
```